# str.format() error for printing floats in Python 2.6

Tags: python, string-formatting, python-2.6

I'm trying to print some floats using Python's str.format(). Here's a sample code

```
table = {'pi':3.1415926}
for variable, value in table.items():
    print '{0:10} ==> {0:.2f}'.format(variable, value)
```

I get the following error when I do this

```
ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'
```

I don't understand why Python thinks 3.1415926 is a string.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the positions backwards:

```
table = {'pi':3.1415926}
for variable, value in table.items():
    print '{0} ==> {1:.2f}'.format(variable, value)

pi ==> 3.14
```

Or simply remove the variable unless you actually want to print pi and iterate over the values:

```
for  value in table.values():
    print '{0} ==> {0:.2f}'.format(value)

3.1415926 ==> 3.14
```

You can also use the dict with **:

```
table = {'pi':3.1415926}

print '{pi} ==> {pi:.2f}'.format(**table)
```

Comment: @lost.identity, No worries, do you actually want to print pi also?

Comment: Yeah, that was just a small sample code I wrote. I'm planning to print a string instead of pi. Now it works!

Answer (score 3):

When you write {0} it refers to the first argument of the format function. You need to change it to 1.

```
table = {'pi':3.1415926}
for variable, value in table.items():
    print '{0:10} ==> {1:.2f}'.format(variable, value)
```

*Edit* Following @AshwiniChaudhary's comment - in *Python 2.7* you don't even need to specify the numbers and it will automatically use them in order

```
table = {'pi':3.1415926}
for variable, value in table.items():
    print '{:10} ==> {:.2f}'.format(variable, value)
```

Comment: Python 2.6 didn't support automatic numbering of format strings, hence the first option is not going to work.

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful but as Ashwini mentioned it doesn't work for 2.6

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary you're right I didn't pay attention to that. Edited following your comment